# Documentation of nuget.config?

Tags: nuget

I recently read about disableSourceControlIntegration setting in Nuget.config.
Is there any documentation (reference) of applicable settings in NuGet.config (e.g. disableSourceControlIntegration) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while i didn't find any documentation i did dive into the source and find

- repositoryPath
- path-key
- disabledPackageSources
- packageSourceCredentials
- packageSources
- disableSourceControlIntegration
- solution

Comment: Thanks. I think some documentation would be useful though. Created an issue: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2756

Comment: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings appears to be plentiful in documenty goodness.